# ¿Cómo reproducir vídeos de youtube sin tener que añadir el iframe de inserción?

Tags: jquery

He visto una plantilla, que tiene la siguiente estructura:

```
    <div class="top-grid-left-left-grids">
        <div class="col-md-8 top-grid-left-img">
          <div data-video="Bzt6h5uFWOU" id="video"> 
            <img src="images/f12.jpg" alt="Use your own screenshot.">
            <div id="play" style=""></div> 
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="col-md-4 top-grid-left-info">
          <a class="text" href="single.html">Fusce ornare congue ligula vel placerat</a>
          <p>Nam id sollicitudin felis. Nulla non bibendum arcu. Vestibulum non venenatis risus.Suspendisse venenatis venenatis mi.</p>
          <div class="t-grid">
            <ul>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-clock-o"></i> 2h</a></li>
              <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-user"></i> Ornare Congue</a></li>
            </ul>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"> </div>
    </div>
```

Donde la imagen previa se muestra en `<img src="images/f12.jpg" alt="Use your own screenshot.">`

Y el vídeo se reproduce mediante un `div`

```
<div id="play" style=""></div>
```

Este método lo realiza esta [demostración de esta plantilla](https://p.w3layouts.com/demos/may-2016/01-05-2016/live_info/web/index.html)

¿Como puedo reproducir un vídeo con la url del vídeo usando jQuery, sin tener que añadir un iframe de inserción de youtube?

> Nota: Los datos de los vídeos y la url de la misma las obtengo mediante una consulta a la base de datos mysqli/php.

Comment: Lo mejor para lo que quieres hacer sería usar la [API de YouTube](https://developers.google.com/youtube/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A mi funciona de este modo:

#### HTML

```
<div id="player"></div>
```

#### Javascript (usando la API)

```
     var tag = document.createElement('script');

      tag.src = "https://www.youtube.com/iframe_api";
      var firstScriptTag = document.getElementsByTagName('script')[0];
      firstScriptTag.parentNode.insertBefore(tag, firstScriptTag);

      var player;


window.onYouTubeIframeAPIReady = function() {
//      function onYouTubeIframeAPIReady() {
        player = new YT.Player('player', {
          height: '360',
          width: '640',
          videoId: 'N0foNKDe514',
          events: {
            'onReady': onPlayerReady,
            'onStateChange': onPlayerStateChange
          }
        });
      }



      function onPlayerReady(event) {
        event.target.playVideo();
      }


      var done = false;
      function onPlayerStateChange(event) {
        if (event.data == YT.PlayerState.PLAYING && !done) {
          setTimeout(stopVideo, 6000);
          done = true;
        }
      }
      function stopVideo() {
        player.stopVideo();
      }
```

---

### DEMO

Puedes verlo en **<kbd>[`jsfiddle`](https://jsfiddle.net/acedano/abfnojyd/3/)</kbd>**, ya que con los code snippet de Stackoverflow no funciona.

Comment: si funciona amigo, también lo logre, pero si lo hago de esa manera me tocará poner el código php en la API, y no en el `data` como puedo obtener amigo solo el VIDEO_ID mediante php donde obtengo la url completa desde la base de datos.

Comment: @So12 hay varias forma de hacerlo. Por ejemplo, si la URL es así: `$url="https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0foNKDe514";
$urlParts = explode('=',$url);
$videoId = end($urlParts);
echo $videoId;`  y si fuera así: `https://www.youtube.com/N0foNKDe514` en el `explode` cambias `=` por `/` y listo.

Comment: @So12 no conviene que cambies la temática de la pregunta, ten en cuenta que ya hay varias respuestas tratando de responder al problema original. Si luego surge otra duda es mejor plantearla en una nueva pregunta. El sitio está pensando para que las preguntas queden como referencia para futuros usuarios con el mismo problema. Tanto la pregunta original, como la nueva pregunta son interesantes, deberías dejar esta como la tenías planteada al principio y la de la URL plantearla aparte. En mi anterior comentario te muestro una forma de hacerlo.

Comment: ya creo que es demasiado tarde amigo, ya han dado otras respuesta, tendré en cuenta lo que me has dicho, pensé que podía hacer cambios cuando uno encuentra la solución por parte de uno mismo.

Comment: El problema es que dos preguntas interesantes quedan diluídas en una sola, como acaba justo de suceder y es una pena. La excelente respuesta de @aloMalbarez podría ser trasladada a una eventual nueva pregunta si tú y él están de acuerdo. Así quedan las dos preguntas y sus respuestas como referencia futura para otros usuarios con el mismo problema.

Comment: Amigo tengo esta nueva [pregunta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/178027/cómo-mostrar-el-tiempo-de-un-post-similar-a-facebook-o-stackoverflow) puedes guiarme por favor, voy a editar la pregunta para que acorde de la mejor manera.

Comment: @So12 tú puedes [desde aquí](https://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/178003/revisions) revertir el estado original de la pregunta, tienes que bajar y pulsar en `revertir` donde aparece el número `1` en grande (es la primera versión de la pregunta). Pero advierte a alo de la nueva pregunta para que publique allí su respuesta.

Comment: Hecho amigo gracias :)

Comment: +1 @A.Cedano ¿Ahora, una duda? ¿Estoy haciendo pruebas con este API, pero en una página donde se usa paginación mediante `PHP` y `AJAX`, entonces me surge el problema cuando se usa los links de la paginación al cargar el nuevo contenido dinámicamente el reproductor no se visualiza, es decir, como si no lo carga de nuevo, si hago una `F5` y recargo la nueva página manualmente, sí que lo muestra correctamente, ¿sabes cuál podría ser el problema?

Comment: @Diablo creo que es mejor que lo plantees en una pregunta, pues no se entiende bien si te refieres a que en la paginación pasas un cada vez un vídeo o si te refieres a resultados de la API paginados ¿? En una pregunta dispondrás de espacio para cualquier aclaración y para mostrar la parte del código problemática.

Comment: @A.Cedano digamos que carga solo un video a reproducir en cada petición del paginado, vale, voy a plantear una pregunta nuevo al respecto con el código, gracias.

Answer (score 2):

Por el momento con con jquery no vi una forma de insertar videos sin usar iframe.

Podrias usar adobe

```
<div style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 820px; height: 461.25px; float: none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;">
  <embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/GlIzuTQGgzs?version=3&amp;hl=en_US&amp;rel=0&amp;autohide=1&amp;autoplay=1" wmode="transparent" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" width="100%" height="100%" allowfullscreen="true" title="Adobe Flash Player">
</div>
```

O usando object de hmtl5

```
<object style="width:100%;height:100%;width: 820px; height: 461.25px; float: none; clear: both; margin: 2px auto;" data="http://www.youtube.com/embed/GlIzuTQGgzs">
```

Fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18726480/embed-html5-youtube-video-without-iframe

Comment: Hola, ya logre obtener los resultados mediante un estudio, puedes actualizar su respuesta mediante lo logrado hasta el momento, gracias :)

Answer (score 1):

En php yo suelo usar este snippet

```
/**
 *  Check if input string is a valid YouTube URL
 *  and try to extract the YouTube Video ID from it.
 *
 *  @author Stephan Schmitz <eyecatchup@gmail.com>
 *  @param  $url   string   The string that shall be checked.
 *  @return mixed           Returns YouTube Video ID, or (boolean) false.
 */        
function parse_yturl($url) 
{
    $pattern = '#^(?:https?://)?';    // Optional URL scheme. Either http or https.
    $pattern .= '(?:www\.)?';         // Optional www subdomain.
    $pattern .= '(?:';                // Group host alternatives:
    $pattern .=   'youtu\.be/';       // Either youtu.be,
    $pattern .=   '|youtube\.com';    // or youtube.com
    $pattern .=   '(?:';              // Group path alternatives:
    $pattern .=     '/embed/';        // Either /embed/,
    $pattern .=     '|/v/';           // or /v/,
    $pattern .=     '|/watch\?v=';    // or /watch?v=,    
    $pattern .=     '|/watch\?.+&v='; // or /watch?other_param&v=
    $pattern .=   ')';                // End path alternatives.
    $pattern .= ')';                  // End host alternatives.
    $pattern .= '([\w-]{11})';        // 11 characters (Length of Youtube video ids).
    $pattern .= '(?:.+)?$#x';         // Optional other ending URL parameters.
    preg_match($pattern, $url, $matches);
    return (isset($matches[1])) ? $matches[1] : false;
}
```

Comment: Disculpa amigo he revertido la pregunta original, debido a que existen dos preguntas en la misma, pido disculpas, a lo mejor puedes editar su respuesta como referencia lo que has publicado gracias.

Comment: vale, si sale nueva pregunta pon el link aquí y movemos la respuesta. no encontré preguntas similares. lo que si encontré es al autor del snippet https://stackoverflow.com/users/624466/eyecatchup y el post original https://stackoverflow.com/a/10524505/1423096